# codes to display a smiley and sad face in C++ console

Tags: c++, c++11

i'm a newbie in C++, 
i need a help to get a smiley and sad face using c++ console,
below was the code i got but it was not giving me big smiley face
and sad face too.

i would appreciate it if any one can assist.

thanks.

```
#include<iostream.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

      printf("%C",2);

      std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: `printf(":-)    :-(");`

Comment: If you are doing `C++`, you should not be using `printf`, you should be using `std::cout` and `<iostream>` without the `.h`. Mixing `C` and `C++` is just unneeded.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42743210/841108

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your terminal, these characters may correspond to ASCII codes 1 and 2, which otherwise denote the Start of Header (SOH) and Start of Text (STX) control characters.

You could test this by trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("\1 \2");
}
```

Alternatively, you could use unicode's [emoticons block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm) in conjunction with `wchar`, a suitable locale, and a suitable font to access a wide variety of smiley faces.

Comment: ok, it will be preferable but how to i use emoticons block in conjunction with wchar,

I try the below codes but it is not work, i won't might example.
thanks.

#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    wchar_t buf[] = L"\uD83D\uDE0A";
    wcout << buf << L"\n";
    
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}

Comment: @johnflow: That code is correct, but Unicode smileys are rather new and not present in common fonts.

Comment: @johnflow, MSalters is right here. There are no guarantees your user has a font which includes smiley glyphs and, as others have mentioned, there's no guarantee their terminal will even display the ASCII smileys correctly. I'm afraid I don't use Windows, so your code won't compile for me.

Answer (score 2):

[ASCII codes for smileys](http://chexed.com/ComputerTips/asciicodes.php) are `1` and `2`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%c %c\n", 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: highly unstable, might cause your computer to explode! (*not really*) You should use Karthik T's suggestion :)

**Edit**

Seriously, you should use this only for fun. It may work or it may not work, depending on terminal emulator you are using. It is working on my Windows 8 cmd.exe screen, but it is not working in Putty via ssh.

Comment: Those are control codes that are invisible when printed. Holding down alt does not get you ASCII.

Comment: It does on my terminal - Windows 8, MSVC10

Comment: But we all remember what it is like when you print some random memory contents - if you are lucky, you may hear some music, too :)

Comment: @chris [0x01 byte maps to U+263a Unicode codepoint in cp437 *in some contexts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)